# What is the best way to perform an assertion for numbers that are off by &quot;.1&quot; in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, testcafe, browser-automation, end-to-end

I need some assistance.This is a weird one.Basically I am writing out some testcafe tests where:
a user goes to the order summary page and verifies that the total on the check out page matches the total on the order details page.

The issue:
There are instances where the order details total is off by a penny(not a bug worthy of fixing any time soon. according to the developers).So for example, on the checkout page your order total is $3.50. On the order details page the total is $3.51

Is there a way to combat a penny extra in a testcafe assertion?

Here is what my assertion looks like:

```
await t
        .expect(totalOnCheckoutPage)
        .eql(totalOnOrderDetails);
```

totalOnCheckoutPage and totalOnOrderDetails are selector variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write custom util to round. Sample

```js
function round(x, precision) {
    var y = +x + (precision === undefined ? 0.5 : precision/2);
    return y - (y % (precision === undefined ? 1 : +precision));
}
console.log(round(3.51, 0.1))
console.log(round(3.55, 0.1))
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Answer (score 1):

You can try Within assertion method

```
await t.expect(5).within(3, 10, 'this assertion will pass');
```

extract the inner text of both values, and add the needed round off range

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/assertion-api.html#within